# "pip install selenium" not working // using python 3 // windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cmd, pip

I cannot install selenium. I have python 3.7 and window 10.

These are some of the things i have tried and the outcome:

C:\Users\dani>pip install selenium
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\dani>sudo pip install selenium
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\dani>pip3 install selenium
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\dani>conda install selenium
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\dani>pip install -U selenium
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: `pip` does not come preinstalled on windows; you must install it yourself.  Have you done so?

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you were installing your python you didn't click the checkbox for python PATH. Delete python and install it again and click the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't install it on your Windows, this might be the reason. Otherwise did you check if it's registered to PATH?

====================

I had the same problem that you are having.
From the instructions given on the internet it is very clear that this command must be given from inside Python's IDLE interface, but that is wrong.
You should open a DOS command prompt as administrator and then execute the commands. To find out if PIP exists on your computer type at the DOS prompt (PIP) and press enter. wait a few moments and you will see the list of commands. If it does not work, PIP is not installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Install pip

Step 1. Check the python version

Step2. Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to a folder on your computer.

Step3. Install pip by following command `python3.7 get-pip.p`y or `python3 get-pip.py`